# Problemas com a pasta vendor/bin de uma aplicação Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Estou tentando fazer deploy de uma aplicação laravel tanto na AWS(Amazon Web Services) quanto na Heroku, e ambos acusaram erros no phpunit dentro da pasta vendor.

Depois de várias pesquisas(que já me custaram umas 6 horas) finalmente achei o erro  dentro da pasta vendor/bin onde praticamente todos os arquivos estão corrompidos.

Esses são os arquivos corrompidos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eles estão com os seguintes erros:

Ex: vendor/bin/dep

```
    #!/usr/bin/env sh

dir=$(cd "${0%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; cd "../deployer/deployer/bin" && pwd)

if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ]; then
    case $(which php) in
        $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/*)
            # We are in Cygwin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
            dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
            ;;
    esac
fi

"${dir}/dep" "$@"
```

Ex: vendor/bin/php-parse:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

dir=$(cd "${0%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; cd "../nikic/php-parser/bin" && pwd)

if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ]; then
    case $(which php) in
        $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/*)
            # We are in Cygwin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
            dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
            ;;
    esac
fi

"${dir}/php-parse" "$@"
```

E algumas outras também.

Alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Exclui a pasta vendor, adiciona no .gitignore e na vpn roda o `composer install`.

Comment: É interessante apagar o composer.lock também.

Comment: Eu fiz exatamente o que você falou, apaguei o vendor, e também o que o CypherPotato disse e apaguei o composer.lock, e ainda dava erro, então li vários tutoriais gringos e percebi que o erro acontecia pois algumas das dependências que estavam no require-dev estavam sendo necessárias no require, então comecei a colocar uma por uma as dependências do require-dev no require conforme davam erro, mas isso levaria muito tempo então copiei e colei tudo, agora estou com outro erro, quando uso o "heroku open", não abre o site, aparece o erro "Não foi possível acessar esse site". Alguma ideia ?

Comment: A propósito, já configurei o Procfile.